# ROS_ETC_DIR usage

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to take advantage of the ROS_ETC_DIR in some packages, but I have a few points of confusion about it:

- My reading of [REP-123](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0123.html) suggests that ROS_ETC_DIR should be `/etc/ros` (or `/etc/ros/hydro`), but it's actually `/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros`.
- When I have an overlay workspace, and I source the workspace's  `devel/setup.bash`, ROS_ETC_DIR still just points to `/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros`
- When I make the install space, I see `install/etc` get generated. However, when I `source install/setup.bash`, I still get ROS_ETC_DIR pointing to `/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros`.
- In the install space, if I create a directory for my package, it is findable using `catkin_find mypackage --etc`

Is the theory that in develspace, anything I would be putting in the `etc` folder will just be in my source and thus findable that way? What about files which are templated or otherwise generated? Should they hang out in `devel` or is a generated configuration file a sign that I am doing something wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125811/ros_etc_dir-usage/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no official answer. This is just my personal understanding of the situation regarding `/etc`.

Current ROS behavior using `/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros` seems to violate the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, because setting `$PREFIX=/usr` would place things under `/usr/etc`, which is specifically disallowed. Since people seldom build ROS with that prefix, the problem is more potential than acute.

We still have not resolved that problem. It requires some REP updates, and came up too late in the Hydro release cycle. It should probably be discussed now and fixed in Indigo.

There are relatively few ROS packages installing files using `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_ETC_DESTINATION}`. They need to be looked at on a case-by-case basis, but my feeling is that most of them should use `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}` instead. That probably helps solve most of the issues you mentioned with access to both generated and source files.

There is a separate issue with packages for managing entire robots, like some of yours. For them, there are cases where things like upstart files need to be installed under the *system* `/etc` directory. That was never handled by  `ROS_ETC_DIR`, anyway. We need to specify how and when such operations are appropriate.

**EDIT**: Bloom support for conffiles is a bigger problem, best discussed in [your issue #226](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/226). The problem remains that neither `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_ETC_DESTINATION}` *nor* `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}` are appropriate for admin-customizable configuration data.

As far as I know, no standard forbids putting default config data in `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/etc`, but as you know it needs special handling to avoid getting overwritten by **apt-get**.

Common Linux practice would probably install them in the global `/etc/package_name` directory, then provide a `~/.package_name` for per-user settings.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-02-04**:
For installing upstart jobs and udev rules, yes, we just copy them into `/etc` as an absolute path regardless. This is not cross-platform, but upstart and udev are peculiarities of Ubuntu regardless, so the cross-platform consideration is not as much in play.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-02-05**:
The specific reason to want etc over share is to make it clear that the file is intended to be user-alterable configuration, despite originating from package management. I've filed a ticket regarding this behaviour: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/226 .